# Angular2 materialize sideNav is not a function

Tags: angular, materialize

I have this problem with sideNav of the Materialize framework: "sideNav is not a function".

I followed all the steps in this tutorial: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize

If i execute $(".button-collapse").sideNav(); on the browser console then it starts working so i thought it was a problem regarding the fact that that function wastn't there at execution time.
I did many tries on putting it at the end of the bundle until i did this finanally:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function () {
      $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    })();
  </script>
```

Same problem persists... sideNav is not a function but works executing it on the console.

Someone can help?
Thanks

Comment: I even tried to execute $(".button-collapse").sideNav(); onclick of the menù button but nothing worked

Comment: Ok i found a workaround that is putting the function in document.ready. But even if i put the function on ngAfterViewInit it doesn't work... houldn't it be the same thing as document.ready??  So works only if i wrap it inside document.ready

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
First of all i was using the Angular-CLI version with webpack.

In the angular2-materialize docs there is a leak. They didn't mention 2 things they should:
- Ovvious: after importing the library they don't mention to put it in the imports,
- Add: import 'materialize-css'; ,  before the import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';

Comment: Now i got other errors on other materialize components... like tooltip: ERROR TypeError: k.velocity is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (materialize.js:3)